HTML / JS Trying to cycle through font options on website with a switch case but its not functioning
I have 6 different options for fonts and I created a button in HTML to call a function onclick. I click it once adn the change works, but when I click it again it does nothing. Definitely missing something and I can''t figure out what it is.


function changeFont() {
  var font = "Arial";
  var fontNum = 1;

  fontNum++;

  switch (fontNum) {
    case 1:
      font = "Josefin Sans";
      break;
    case 2:
      font = "Montserrat";
      break;
    case 3:
      font = "Lora";
      break;
    case 4:
      font = "Suse";
      break;
    case 5:
      font = "Fenix";
      break;
    case 6:
      font = "Courier Prime";
  }

  document.body.style.fontFamily = font;

  if (fontNum >= 6) {
    fontNum = 0;
  }
}
<input type="button" id="font-toggle" value="Aa" onclick="changeFont()" />



It changes to Montserrat, but nothing after.
Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

You are setting fontNum = 1 on every click so it always moves up to 2 and on the next click, you re-initialize it to 1 before you set it back to 2.  You need to have that variable outside of the function so it retains its value from one click to the next

You declared var fontNum = 1 in the click event which means its value is not saved for next click, so when you click the button fontNum changes from 1 to 2 => font become "Montserrat" everytime.
Move the fontNum out of the function and it'll work.

well, i feel like a dunce. thank you

While you already have an answer I still want to give you another answer that solves the issue with a completely different approach. 
Your code could be simplified a lot and change/remove the issue with it.
Your code is not very abstract and could be simplified a lot. Simply sue an array for your fonts and then toggle through the array.
To get to the start of the array you can use fontNum = (fontNum + 1) % Fonts.length;. This will also remain to work when adding more fonts to the array. There will be no further need to change the function code.


const Fonts = ['Arial', 'Josefin Sans', 'Montserrat', 'Lora', 'Suse', 'Fenix', 'Courier Prime'];
let fontNum = 0;

function changeFont() {
  fontNum = (fontNum + 1) % Fonts.length;
  document.body.style.fontFamily = Fonts[fontNum];
  
  // shows current selected Font
  console.clear()
  console.log(Fonts[fontNum]);
}
<input type="button" id="font-toggle" value="Aa" onclick="changeFont()" />




Solid coding, thank you.

Do some changes according to it.


var fontNum = 0;

function changeFont() {
  var font;
  fontNum++;

  switch (fontNum) {
    case 1:
      font = "Josefin Sans";
      break;
    case 2:
      font = "Montserrat";
      break;
    case 3:
      font = "Lora";
      break;
    case 4:
      font = "Suse";
      break;
    case 5:
      font = "Fenix";
      break;
    case 6:
      font = "Courier Prime";
      break;
    default:
      font = "Arial";
      fontNum = 0;  // Reset fontNum after the last case
  }

  document.body.style.fontFamily = font;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(font);
}
<input type="button" id="font-toggle" value="Aa" onclick="changeFont()" />




Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. Add more details in the form of an explanation of your changes. From code alone, it is hard to know what changes you made. Especially by not formatting your code and text it was very hard to see how your answer would solve it. I guess that is also the reason why you got downvoted.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
